# Finding the derivative of a quadratic function at a particular point

Tags: calculus

The question states:

> Suppose $f(x)=-5x^2+x-3$.
>
> Find $f'(-1)$.

So I worked out the problem as follows:

\begin{align*}
f'(-1)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-5(h^2+1)+h-13}{h} \\
&=\frac{-5h^2+h-18}{h} \\
&=\frac{h^2\left(-5+\frac{h}{h^2}-\frac{18}{h^2}\right)}{h^2\left(\frac{h}{h^2}\right)}
\end{align*}
In which the third step I assume I am doing it wrong because I believe factoring out only works if I have an expression in the denominator instead of just the variable $h$.

Would anyone mind telling me where I am going wrong in this problem?

Comment: Do you mean to define $f(x)$ rather than $f'(x)$?

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, typo. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step isn't quite correct. We have

\begin{align}
f(-1 + h) - f(-1) &= -5(-1 + h)^2 + (-1 + h) -3 - \Big(-5(-1)^2 + (-1) - 3\Big) \\
&= -5(1 - 2h + h^2) - 4 + h - (-5 - 1 - 3) \\
&= -5h^2 + 11 h -9 + 9 \\
&= -5h^2 + 11h
\end{align}

Hence, you want

$$f'(-1) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-5h^2 + 11h}{h}$$

Comment: Thank you, I went over it again and this time wrote out every step (even though I hate to) and I got it. I seem to make mistakes when I try to do 3 to 4 steps at a time, I guess I will have to slow it down.

Answer (score 4):

Equivalently to @T's post, $f'(-1)$ exists if the following limit is $<\infty$, so:

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x-(-1)}=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{-5x^2+x-3+9}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{-5x^2+x+6}{x+1}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{-(x+1)(5x-6)}{x+1}=+11$$

Comment: We talked about that in class however we haven't gone over it. The best we can do as of now is get to the final step T.Bongers showed and plug in .0001 for h. However this is nice to know, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I see. I am glad I did something small here for you additionally. :-)

Comment: Nice nice, @Babak! (+)

Comment: I like see the use of the derivative's definition, @BabakS. +1

Comment: Hello, dear Babak! How are you this fine day?

Comment: @amWhy: Exhausted of teaching, Speaking and standing within blackboard for hours.